# Adding padding to the drop down options for <select)>

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I wanted to add spacing between  the options when the drop down appears. So how can I implement padding to all the options and increase the space between the options.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwMwd.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I style a <select> dropdown with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css)

Comment: Welcome.  Just a heads up, I don't believe option spacing is fully supported by most browsers.  That said, adding styles (height, line-height, padding) to 'option' should be the direction you're looking for.